# Update a table column in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I check for the existence of a column in a table. If it exists, I update a column in a 2nd table based on the column in first table.

The issue is, the update is getting executed when it should not be and results in an error.

I check for the existence of column `Requested_by` in table `Service_requests_details`, 
I then update a column in `service_requests` based on column `requested_by` in table `Service_Requests_Details`.

The point is, `Requested_By` might not exist in table `Service_requests_details`.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N'Requested_By' and object_ID = object_ID(N'Service_Requests_Details'))
BEGIN
      Update SR
      Set SR.Requested_By  = SRD.Requested_By 
      FROM Service_Requests SR
      INNER JOIN Service_Requests_Details SRD ON SRD.Request_Index = SR.Service_Request_Index
END
GO
```

Update:
Thanks everyone who responded. Thanks @SqlAcid for the answer.

Comment: What does this return? SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N'Requested_By' and object_ID = object_ID(N'Service_Requests_Details'.    Remember, parameters to procedures are also kept in sys.columns, you could have procedure with the same name...

Comment: Try adding the extra 'U' to you object_id() (The second parameter is the object type, adding 'U' is for tables)

Comment: As suggested by Dylan, I tried the same with Information_Schema.columns, and ran into the same issue

Comment: In general, this is a very bad idea; columns on tables should be thought of as fixed attributes of the entity they represent.

That being said, what exactly is the error that you are getting?  My guess is that your script won't pass the optimizer check because you're trying to update from a column that doesn't exist

Comment: @StuartAinsworth: The update is a 1 time update and after that there is a need to delete that column from the other table. So we just want to make sure that the script executes successfully when ran multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the parser will still evaluate your update statement and fail even when the IF EXISTS is false; you could use sp_executesql to get around it:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N'Requested_By' and object_ID = object_ID(N'Service_Requests_Details')) 
BEGIN 
  set @sql = 'Update SR 
      Set SR.Requested_By  = SRD.Requested_By  
      FROM Service_Requests SR 
      INNER JOIN Service_Requests_Details SRD ON SRD.Request_Index = SR.Service_Request_Index'
  exec sp_executesql @sql
END 
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would do in SQL 2008, don't have a SQL 2005 instance handy to see if it works in there, but worth a try:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Service_Requests_Details' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Requested_By')
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

Comment: This should work in SQL 2005...   Check the link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348(v=SQL.90).aspx